# I have a c# WPF application. I made it into a class library. The dll is not recognized when I try to use it. The frameworks are all the same

Tags: c#, wpf

I changed a WPF application(.exe) into a class library(.dll) using Visual Studio 13. When I try to use it, it is not recognized. I have changed the frameworks to 4.0 everywhere with no success. I have made the path very short, as someone in another post suggested, which did not work. In my original program I have several user controls. Sometime ago, I was able to do all these with no problems. At that time, when I built the class library, automatically the following line appeared on top my user controls. Now it is not there when I build the class library.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
```

I appreciate any suggestions to resolve the issue.

Thanks, Ray.

Comment: What does _"When I try to use it"_ mean?  _How_ are you trying to use it?

Comment: I changed the build property  to class library and got rid off the APP.

Comment: Then in another application program, I use it as a reference. It does accept it. But It is not accessible.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just simply convert an exe into a class library like that. What did you do to convert it?